# Div alignment is not working

Tags: html, css

I am having a main div `PricingBar` inside that i have 3 sub div's . while keeping `PricingBar` `height: auto;` sub div's are displaying out of the `PricingBar`

[image]

Here Green color border is `PricingBar`

**Option A, Option B, Option C** are sub div's

**html code:**

```
<div id="PriceBar">
   <div id="OptionA">
     <h2>Option A</h2>
     <table class="optiontable">
        <tr><td class="column1">Setup Fee: </td><td><span>&#36;250.00</span> (includes 10 customized apparel pieces)</td></tr>
         <tr><td class="column1">Monthly Fee:</td><td><span>&#36;25.00</span></td></tr>
     </table>
   </div>
   <div id="OptionB">
     <h2>Option B</h2>
     <table class="optiontable">
        <tr><td class="column1">Setup Fee:</td><td><span>&#36;99.00</span> (includes 10 customized apparel pieces)</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="column1">Monthly Fee:</td><td><span>&#36;40.00</span></td></tr>
      </table>
   </div>
   <div id="OptionC">
     <h2>Option C</h2>
     <table class="optiontable">
          <tr><td class="column1">Setup Fee:</td><td>Refund</td></tr>
          <tr><td class="column1">Monthly Fee:</td><td>Refunded</td></tr>
      </table>
   </div>
</div>
```

**css code:**

```
#PriceBar{
    width: 1004px;
    position: relative;
    height:auto;
    padding:10px;
    border: 2px solid green;
    background:#930;
    float: inherit;

}

#OptionA, #OptionB, #OptionC{
    margin: 10px 20px;
    padding: 5px;
    float: left;
    width: 283px;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #FFF;
    -webkit-border-radius:15px;
    -mox-border-radius:15px;
    border-radius:15px;
}

#OptionA h2, #OptionB h2, #OptionC h2{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #006A8E;
}
table.optiontable tr td{
    padding: 10px 5px;
    color: #B9B196;
}
td.column1{
    width:100px;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    color: #252525 !important;
}
table.optiontable tr td span{
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: I assume you want the divs in question to be wholly contained in the red bar?

Comment: Your question is indeed missing.

Comment: It is because you have a floating element inside the PriceBar div.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since all your `div` elements float, the "red bar" basically "forgets" that it is the container for them. Simply add an `overflow:auto;` to make it remember. I also tend to add `zoom:1` for IE.

Answer (score 3):

because of **float** of sub div's

add overflow:hidden to PricingBar

```
#PriceBar{
    width: 1004px;
    position: relative;
    height:auto;
    padding:10px;
    border: 2px solid green;
    background:#930;
    float: inherit;

    overflow:hidden;/*!!!*/

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add overflow:hidden to your #PriceBar style should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Demo
http://jsfiddle.net/8aduV/1/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the height:auto;

Just make it a table, as it would be crossbrowser:

```
<table id="PriceBar">
    <tr>
        <td id="OptionA">
            <h2>Option A</h2>
            <table class="optiontable">
                <tr><td class="column1">Setup Fee: </td><td><span>&#36;250.00</span> (includes 10 customized apparel pieces)</td></tr>
                <tr><td class="column1">Monthly Fee:</td><td><span>&#36;25.00</span></td></tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td id="OptionB">
            <h2>Option B</h2>
            <table class="optiontable">
                <tr><td class="column1">Setup Fee:</td><td><span>&#36;99.00</span> (includes 10 customized apparel pieces)</td></tr>
                <tr><td class="column1">Monthly Fee:</td><td><span>&#36;40.00</span></td></tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td id="OptionC">
            <h2>Option C</h2>
            <table class="optiontable">
                <tr><td class="column1">Setup Fee:</td><td>Refund</td></tr>
                <tr><td class="column1">Monthly Fee:</td><td>Refunded</td></tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
​
```

Answer (score -1):

It's Normal, If you have an height in auto; in your two first block your block is in two lines, in the third, text it's just in one block, try whith "min-height" in every "tr"

```
tr{
    min-height:40px;
}
```

Or, other solution is to create a global table, for all your code. your three colums was link, and you don't have this problem :p

For debuging, Use [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/firebug/) it's more easy for testing your html code and CSS.

I hope I help you ;-P

Comment: -1. My question is about the main div , and also I cant keep `min-height` because my each `<tr>` (sometimes its lessthan 40px).

Comment: Ok, sorry ^^ I want to improve my english :p